# How to spawn a vbs script in Expect?

Tags: process, kill, expect, pid

I have a vbs script that kills a process. This script is provided with a pid as argument. I would like to spawn this script from an expect script. But when i write:

```
spawn KillProcess.vbs pid_to_kill
```

I get the error: "no such file or directory". Btw I am new to expect :)

But what am i doing wrong?

The vbs script is located in the same folder as the expect script.

Comment: oh i noticed that i forgot $ in front of pid_to_kill. But i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to launch the VBS program with `cscript`:

```
spawn cscript KillProcess.vbs $pid_to_kill
```

http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html